# How to convert string from text file to Int

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read from a text file which contains strings of numbers and I want to be able to convert each line from the file into Int and store it in an array so I am able to do maths on it later date.

This is what I have tried within Visual Studio and it gives a message of "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader List1 = new StreamReader("path of text file.txt"))
    {
        string input;
        List<string> High256 = new List<string>();
        while((input = List1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(input);
        }
        High256.Add(input);
        Console.WriteLine(High256);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debuged and checked the input? ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you used a debugger or other diagnostics (e.g. writing the value of `input` to the console) to see which value is failing?

Comment: Post sample of data in file.

Comment: What value you are getting in `input` variable?

Comment: `int[] array = File.ReadLines("path of text file.txt").Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)).Select(line => int.Parse(line)).ToArray();`

Comment: The max vakue for an Int32 is 2147483647 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).  If the string you are reading is larger than that when you attempt to convert it will throw an error.  As others have stated, please post the data that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you can convert to an int or not first.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var List1 = new File.ReadAllLines("path of text file.txt");

        string input;
        List<string> High256 = new List<string>();
        foreach(var item in List1)
        {

            if(int.TryParse(item?.Trim(), out var tempInt))
              {
                  High256.Add(tempInt);
                  Console.WriteLine(High256);
              }


        }


}
```

or in one line:

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines("path")
.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out var temp))
.Select(t=>int.Parse(t.Trim())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq and do next thing:

```
    int[] array = File.ReadAllLines("path").Select(t=>Convert.ToInt32(t)).ToArray();
```

this will read all lines from file and convert each line to int32 type,finally you get int array!

Comment: If there is problem,please attach file

Comment: This will not solve the FormatException which OP is getting

Comment: @AmirNo-Family: Well, is it not better that he fixes the file than make the code more forgiving? The only description we have of the file is "a text file which contains strings of numbers". If it only is to contain numbers he should not need to make the code work for non numbers, it instead seems to be a error that is in the file.